# Nano text editor not warning when opening file already open

Tags: warnings, edit, redhat, nano

**Context**: I recently started using the nano text editor on a new machine (Red Hat based).

There's no GUI. I'm doing everything through the terminal. I'm using tmux to run multiple commands at once.

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Open up an existing file in nano
2. Open up that same file in nano in a separate instance (without terminating the first instance) e.g. in another tmux pane

**Expected output**:

Nano gives a warning in step 2 along the lines of

> this file is currently being edited by nano with PID x. Do you wish to continue?

This is what I have experienced on every other machine I've used nano on

**Observed output**:

Nano executes step 2 without warning. Only when I try to save the file does it alert me that someone else has the file open.

**Issue**:

This is an issue because sometimes I:

- open file x in instance A
- modify but don't save
- do something else
- forget that I haven't saved my modifications to file x, and forget that it's still open
- open file x in instance B
- make more modifications in instance B
- try to save
- be warned that 2 instances are opened
- realise that I've made changes to 2 different unsaved instances of the one file